# Excel Macro to compare data from 2 sheets and paste values over on match

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets, I want to compare if the data in sheet 1 for first name and last name (Column A and B) are found in sheet 2 (Also Column A and B), where the first name is in column A and Last Name in column B. If the first and last name from sheet1 are found within sheet2, and also if the ID number in sheet 2 (column E) for that row is equal to 2, then I want to copy over the customer detail row (Column D) from sheet2 into column P of Sheet 1.

I feel like the code I have below should work, but it isn't pasting the customer data into column P of sheet1 for me. Any ideas why?

```
Sub matchandpaste()


Dim cell, cell2, revenue As Range
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sheet1, sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim temp, firstName, lastName As String

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

Set Sheet1 = wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sheet2 = wbk.Sheets("Sheet2")


For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row)
    lastName = cell.Value
    firstName = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Set revenue = cell.Offset(0, 14)
    For Each cell2 In sheet2.Range("B2:B" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row)
        If lastName = cell2.Value And firstName = cell2.Offset(0, -1).Value And cell2.Offset(0, 3).Value = 2 Then
            revenue = cell2.Offset(0, 2).Value
        End If
    Next cell2
Next cell
```

Comment: No, because I want to copy the data from column E in Sheet 2, to Column P in sheet 1, so I set `revenue` as the variable to the place where I want to paste the data

Comment: @KPaul No problem, I can imagine it is quite difficult to visualize without having the dataset. I'm sure this could also be done with a custom function as you suggested, although I want to get to the bottom of the problem with this macro because it seems like it should work, but it is driving me crazy.

Comment: See @Jarom's response below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to put a `.value` at the end of the `revenue` range variable.  Like this:

```
Sub matchandpaste()


Dim cell, cell2, revenue As Range
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sheet1, sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim temp, firstName, lastName As String

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

Set Sheet1 = wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sheet2 = wbk.Sheets("Sheet2")


For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row)
    lastName = cell.Value
    firstName = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Set revenue = cell.Offset(0, 14)
    For Each cell2 In sheet2.Range("B2:B" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row)
        If lastName = cell2.Value And firstName = cell2.Offset(0, -1).Value And cell2.Offset(0, 3).Value = 2 Then
            revenue.value = cell2.Offset(0, 2).Value
        End If
    Next cell2

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Great Catch, I cannot believe I looked over the code so many times and kept missing this.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a little bit of messing around with the code before I realized the problem.  It doesn't really jump out at you hahaha!