# Combine data from 2 worksheet based on ID, while inserting row

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets:

- `Sheet1` has a unique `ID` in Column `A`.
- `Sheet2` *may* have two or more consecutive rows of data with a matching `ID`.

I need to **match** the `ID`s and copy data from columns `B` & `C` into the same columns in `Sheet1`. I can do that by tweaking the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617943/excel-macro-to-compare-data-from-2-sheets-and-paste-values-over-on-match).

However, I would also like to copy (eventual) second, third, etc. rows also with matching `ID` from `Sheet2` to **new rows** in `Sheet1`.

[image: *Examples (images)*]

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

Consider running SQL with an inner join query between both sheets. Below assumes a blank sheet named *OUTPUT* with headers in first row:

```
' ADO OBJECTS
Dim xlConn As Object, rs As Object

Set xlConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' CURRENT WORKBOOK CONNECTION
xlConn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
              & "DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";"

' JOIN QUERY
strSQL = "SELECT t1.ID, t2.[Name], t2.Age" _
           & " FROM [Sheet1$] t1" _
           & " INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID"

' OUTPUT RESULTS
rs.Open strSQL, xlConn

Worksheets("OUTPUT").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
xlConn.Close
```

Comment: Nice SQL based answer, but perhaps use 2007 Office System Driver (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider) as per http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2017/02/using-2007-office-system-driver-to.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that is an interesting solution. I wanted to test it out, however I get an error at the workbook connection. I assume it is an issue due to the Microsoft Excel Driver.

Comment: What is your environment? OS? Bit type? Office version? You can use either an OLEDB or ODBC. This answer will only work for Excel for Windows.

Comment: @Parfait Windows 10, 64-bit, Excel 2016. Admittedly, I would like a solution that is workable also on Mac, but Windows would be a good start. In either case, your comment made me realize I do not know how to run the SQL (I had originally tried to paste the code onto VBA).

Comment: See update. I did not initialize the ADO connection and recordset objects. And yes, this only works on Windows Excel since you are using the Jet/ACE SQL Engine (Windows .dll files and the very engine of MS Access!) which can query Access databases, Excel workbooks, even txt/csv files.

Answer (score 0):

You can find and match related informations by ID with a VLOOKUP.

> =VLOOKUP(lookup value, range containing the lookup value, the column number in the range containing the return value, optionally specify
>   TRUE for approximate match or FALSE for an exact match)

Your example as a common Excel formula:

```
=VLOOKUP("ID from Sheet1", "Range in Sheet2", "Row number of Sheet 2 you want to add", FALSE "for exact match")
```

This can be also executed as VBA:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP("ID from Sheet1", "Range in Sheet2", "Row number of Sheet 2 you want to add", FALSE "for exact match")
```